# ASP.NET Core Tag Helper Arrays

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.0 web application that generates a multi-select list box using [bootstrap-multiselect](http://davidstutz.de/bootstrap-multiselect/#getting-started) (basically a prettied up list box control)

The code generated is shown:

```
<select class="multiselect-ui form-control" id="Issues" multiple="multiple" name="Issues">
    <option selected="selected" value="1">Dilapidated Structures</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="3">Junk on Premises</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="4">Junk Vehicles</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="5">Minor Maintenance</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="6">Miscellaneous</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="7">Overgrowth</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="8">Right of Way</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="9">Sidewalks</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="10">Trash</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="2">Weeds/High Grass</option>
</select>
```

When this is submitted in a form, I see the `Issues` being added to the URL like so:

```
/Cases?Issues=1&Issues=3&Issues=4&Issues=5 ...
```

This is great and I am able to retrieve the values in my controller using a `List<string>` object.  My question is, how would I add a hyperlink to the page that uses the values already sent via GET?  Basically I would like to use Tag Helpers, but there is no way to add an array of values that I've found.  There are dictionary key/pairs, but of course you are not able to add multiple values with the same key.  I would like to be able to reference a `List<string>` in the tag helper itself (the following does not work, but should give an idea of what I'm after if I am sending the `List<string>` back using ViewBag):

```
<a asp-route-Issues=@ViewBag.IssuesList>Next</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out through [this link](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4560) that this feature isn't implemented.  I used `@Url.Action` to build my link as shown (where `ViewBag.IssuesList` contains the `List<string>` -- I also left out some paramters for brevity:

`<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Cases", new { Issues = ViewBag.IssuesList })">Previous</a>`